# shouldn't access to mapped types be an union with undefined?

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation, mapped-types

I have a type like this:

```js
type MyType = {
  [key:string]:number
}

const someValue = MyType.whatever // the type here should be number|undefined, but it's undefined
```

I mean, it's impossible for MyType to have EVERY string as key. And it seems like an unnecessary thing to do to turn it into

```js
type MyType = {
  [key:string]:number|undefined
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unleast you have an `noUncheckedIndexedAccess: true` in `tsconfig.json`, typescript allows you to acess arrays and records without checks:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let a5 = a[5] // number
//  ^?

let o: Record<string, number> = {a: 123}
let ob = o.b // number
//  ^?
```

This is made because generally you would check for `undefined` yourself if you would expect it to be a possibly invalid key

If you wand a record with optional keys (to enforce user to check them), define it yourself

```
let o1: Partial<Record<string, number>> = {};
let o2: {[key: string]?: number} = {}
```

Comment: Wondering why the property is not called `checkedIndexedAccess` instead of using double negation

Comment: Because it prevents `UncheckedIndexedAccess` which itself is a common thing. Without double negation it would be `requireCheckedIndexedAcess`